# Remove/move files in a directory with filename timestamp pattern

Tags: files, directory, filter, pattern-matching, move

So I have files that need to remove/move/filter.

All files have this pattern like this in a directory, let's say directory `frames` contain this pattern filename `timestamp_in_nanosecond.jpg`.

And this is sample of that files with using pipelined tail from ls. `ls | tail`. (I'm using tail because ls too slow, maybe because too many files to list).

```
.../uwc/frames $ ls | tail
1660649146201561661.jpg
1660649146411875151.jpg
1660649146622526505.jpg
1660649146832063432.jpg
1660649147042957234.jpg
1660649147254488848.jpg
1660649147466753015.jpg
1660649147889093171.jpg
1660649148193314525.jpg
1660649148786199681.jpg
```

What if I want move files to another directory like `frames2` with specified range like this range:

```
 From  1660649147000000000.jpg
 Until 1660649148000000000.jpg
```

Hence, `frames2` dir will contain these files only:

```
1660649147042957234.jpg
1660649147254488848.jpg
1660649147466753015.jpg
1660649147889093171.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard

```
mv 1660649147?????????.jpg frames2/
```

Depending on whether or not you mean to include the upper limit, maybe also

```
mv 1660649148000000000.jpg frames2/
```

If there are too many files for the wildcard to match without running out of buffer space, use `find` instead:

```
find . -name 'frames2' -prune -o -name '1660649147?????????.jpg' -exec mv -t frames2/ {} +
```

Notes

1. The `-name 'frames2' -prune` clause prevents `find` descending into the `frames2` subdirectory. You don't need it (or the `-o` "or") if `frames2` is actually elsewhere.
2. If your `mv` does not have the GNU extension `-t`, change the `-exec` clause to `-exec mv {} frames2/ \;`, but realise it will take considerably longer to complete.

In all cases, you can amend `mv` to `echo mv` to see the set of chosen files without actually moving them.

Comment: So if I filter with this pattern `1660649147?????????.jpg`, I will only move 1 second frames. And `166064914??????????.jpg` I will only move 10 second frames?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira no! The `?` characters match _any character_ (i.e. any digit), so the pattern `1660649147?????????.jpg` matches all file names starting `1660649147`, having nine further characters (digits), and then the suffix `.jpg`. I've updated my answer to show how you can see the set of selected files without actually moving them.

Comment: I meant, 1 second frames doesn't mean 1 frame nor 1 file. Like I said before, the filename pattern is in nanosecond unix timestamp since epoch.

Comment: "_Like I said before, the filename pattern is in nanosecond unix timestamp since epoch_" actually you didn't say that. What you did say was, "_directory frames contain this pattern filename timestamp_in_nanosecond.jpg_". So when you asked if certain patterns would match a "_1 second frame_" and "_10 second frames_"" I took that to mean one frame every second or every 10 seconds. However, if you've got the answer you need, I'm pleased we were able to get there

Comment: Actually I'm still confused, your answer playing with digit number, but I expect I can filter with comparison operator like filter timestamp if `greater than 1660649147000000000` and `less than 1660649148000000000`

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira why would you want to filter? The answers I've given you will only match in the range 1660649147000000000 ≤ _n_ < 1660649148000000000

Comment: What if I want `1660649147000000000 ≤ n < 1660649147500000000`. Is your answer still applied?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira you'd need a different pattern, `1660649147[0-4]????????.jpg`